# Proof of mathematic induction via the property of $\mathbb{N}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Assuming that any nonempty set of positive integers has a minimal element, prove:

If the proposition $P$ is such that

(1) $P(m_0)$ is true,

(2) $P(m)$ is true whenever $P(a)$ is true for all $a$ such that $m_0\leqslant a<m$,

then $P(n)$ is true for all $n\geqslant m_0$.

**My solution:** Let $A$ be the following set $$A=\{n\geqslant m_0: P(n)\  \text{is false}\}$$ Since $m_0\in A$ ($\Rightarrow A\neq \varnothing$) and $A\subset \mathbb{N}$ then $A$ has the smallest element, let's call it $m$. Then $m\in A, \ m\geqslant m_0$ and $P(m)$ is false. Since $P(m_0)$ is true $\Rightarrow$ $P(m_0+1)$ also true $\Rightarrow$$...$$\Rightarrow$ $P(m)$ is true. This is contradiction and hence $A=\varnothing$. Thus $P(m)$ is true for all $m\geqslant m_0$

**EDIT:** Let's define the following set $$A=\{k\geqslant m_0: P(k) \ \text{is false}\}$$ Suppose that this set is non-empty. Then being the subset of $\mathbb{N}$ it has minimal element $m$. Using minimality of $m$ we have that for $a$ such that $m_0\leqslant a<m$ we have that $P(a)$ is true. Then by 2) $P(m)$ is true. But since $m\in A$ we have $P(m)$ is false. This is the contradiction. It follows that the set $A$ is empty meaning that $P(k)$ is true for all $K\geqslant m_0$.

Comment: You never used the fact that $m$ is the least element ($m = m_0$ BTW) and you didn't explain why $P(m_0)$ true implies $P(m)$ is true.   Although $P(m)$ is true *BECAUSE* $m \in A$. And even if you did, that only proves it for $m$, the least element of $A$.  It certainly doesn't prove it for *any* $m\ge m_0$.  For all you know there may be many $n \ge m_0$ but $n \not \in A$.

Comment: Hint:  Let $B = \{k \ge m_0|P(k)$ is *false* $\}$.  Prove that $B$ has no least element.  That would mean $B$ is empty.  And that would mean $P(k)$ is *true* for all $k \ge m_0$.

Comment: Hint:  If $m= \min B$ then for any $a; m_0 \le a < m$ then $a \not \in B$.

Comment: @fleablood, I still can not understand flaws of my proof. In my opinion it is true. I can not  comprehend it's mistakes.

Comment: @fleablood, I have edited my solution. Please take a look at it. Namely, I have edited my set $A$.

Comment: Okay, getting better but $m_0 \not \in A$ because $P(m_0)$ is true, not false.  Don't say $P(m_0)\implies P(m_0 + 1) \implies ... \implies$.  That is what we are trying to prove.  Prove 1) $m=\min A > m_0$ (because $m \ge m_0$ and $m \ne m_0$) and 2) that if $a: m_0 \le a < m$ then $P(a)$ is true.  And by condition 2).....

Comment: @ZFR, it looks like your edited proof is correct to me. I got here by searching for the solution for Herstein's *Topics in Algebra, 2nd edition* problem 10 in ch 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

Let $B = \{k\ge m_0| P(k) \text{ is false}\}\subset \mathbb N$.

Either $B$ is empty; or $B$ has a minimum element.

If $B$ has a minimum element $m = \min B$, then what can you say about $a: m_0 \le a < m$?[$*$]  Is $P(a)$ true or false or can you not determine.

And what does condition 2) tell you about whether $P(m)$ is true or not? And what does $m = \min B$ tell you about whether $P(m)$ is true or not?

Is a minimum element of $B$ possible?  What does it mean if it isn't?

[$*$]  Warning:  Do any $m_0 \le a < m$ exist?  Do we know that $m > m_0$.

Comment: After rereading of initial post i have realized that it containts serious flaws and I have corrected them in my EDIT. You can take a look.